# Minecraft /testfor Players Using Items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am trying to create a hydration system for my Minecraft adventure map that displays hydration levels on the scoreboard. To restore the players hydration a player should need to drink a water bottle, and so I figured this command would do the trick: `/testfor @p {stat.useItem:373}`

However I receive an error: `(player) did not match the required data structure`

Does anyone know why I recieve this error and if there is any way to make the command work? (preferably without using scoreboard values instead as I want to use the scoreboard values to display the hydration levels themselves)

Answer (score 3):

`stat.useItem` is not a NBTag, it's a scoreboard objective type. Moreover, if it even was an data tag, you'd be testing for someone who has used an item 373 times, not someone who's used water once.

You **are** going to need to use scoreboard objectives for this. I feel like your concern may be a misunderstanding though; you can have as many different objectives as you want, and don't have to display the ones you don't want to be seen.

To set up this objective, type:

```
/scoreboard objectives add drankWater stat.useItem.minecraft.potion
```

You can then test for people who drank water like this:

```
/testfor @a[score_drankWater_min=1]
```

And reset their score to 0 like this:

```
/scoreboard players set @a[score_drankWater_min=1] drankWater 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot technically detect whether or not it's specifically a water bottle, unless you name it and have it `testfor` the player to have used it and hold it.

Answer (score -2):

I'm fairly certain you use [ ] in place of { }